# Wilcoxon test statistic

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I learned WSR (Wilcoxon signed rank test) several years ago, and today one of my friends suggest different test statistics on WSR. At first, I thought he was wrong; however, I did found some sources which were citing the **positive rank sum** as W test statistic. Such as these links suggests: http://courses.wcupa.edu/rbove/Berenson/CD-ROM%20Topics/topice-10_5.pdf http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/5601/notes/wilcox.pdf

According to my undergrads stat, we choose the **min(W+,W-)** as the test statistic. for example: http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/BS704_Nonparametric/BS704_Nonparametric6.html

On wiki, it suggest that **W = abs(W+ minus W-)**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#Test_procedure

Why does WSR test has so many "alternative" test statistics? Is there many versions of WSR? When to use which test statistics? I am confused now. Please share any insights with me, many thanks.

#

I would like to edit this question. I just tried to write functions to calculate z scores in r. using two equations below, I was able to get same absolute z-scores using Negative rank sum, Positive rank sum, or absolute rank sum:

these data were replicates from an online source https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqCg2tb4wJ0

> n =non-zero ranking sample size
>
> w+ = 75
>
> w- = 16
>
> |w| = 75-16=59
>
> n = 13

for neg or pos

> z <- function(w,n){
>     (w-(n*(n+1)/4))/(sqrt((n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/24)))
>
> }

for absolute

> z1 <- function(w,n){
>     (w)/sqrt((n*(n+1)*(2*n+1))/6)
>   }
>
> z(75,13)
>   [1] 2.061627
>
> z(16,13)
>   [1] -2.061627
>
> z1(59,13)
>   [1] 2.061627

But I'm still confused with it...
Should it considered to be irresponsible for articles and papers to use positive rank sum as w test statistics? Usually people use critical values sheet of w to determine the result right? http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/tables/wilcox_signrank.pdf

On the case above(the youtube link), if we use positive rank sum, the result would be completely opposite.

Please let me know if I was thinking in the right direction.

Comment: There are two different types of Wilcoxon nonparametric tests. (a) One-sample, including a sample of paired differences [often called 'Wilcoxon signed rank' test]. (b) Two-sample test [also called 'Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon' or 'Wilcoxon rank sum' test.] Tests by Mann & Whitney and by Wilcoxon, originally thought to be different, were subsequently proved to be equivalent. Both methods of computing the two-sample test statistic remain in use. Also, various software packages do slightly different versions in search of optimal normal approximations and accommodations to moderate numbers of ties....

Comment: Unless you are computing the test statistics by hand, I suggest you trust reputable statistical analysis software to do the job in a competent manner. For same data all should give essentially the same P-value, even though statistics and exact distributions may differ. (I have used R, SAS, Minitab, SPSS without noticing important discrepancies. Personally, can't recommend Excel, which may have improved since my last contact.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of 2-sample tests in R and in Minitab (software at hand at the moment):

R (simulate fake data):

```
x1 = round(rnorm(30, 100, 15),2);  x2 = round(rnorm(25, 110, 15),2)
sort(x1)
 [1]  67.38  68.20  79.60  80.39  82.42  83.11  84.65  86.45  90.36  93.48  94.14
[12]  97.65  99.56 101.25 102.01 102.63 103.66 103.98 105.82 105.89 106.30 112.02
[23] 113.57 113.73 114.68 117.58 119.63 119.92 120.97 133.46
sort(x2)
 [1]  81.53  91.60  95.55 100.34 102.89 103.39 104.81 105.00 106.02 106.43 106.51
[12] 111.37 111.70 113.26 113.73 114.05 115.09 117.22 118.29 121.24 127.69 132.60
[23] 137.79 137.97 143.20
```

Output

```
wilcox.test(x1, x2)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x1 and x2
W = 218.5, p-value = 0.008366
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(x1, x2) : cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Minitab (input same data used in R):

```
MTB > set c1
DATA>   67.38  68.20  79.60  80.39  82.42  83.11  84.65  86.45  90.36  93.48  94.14
DATA>   97.65  99.56 101.25 102.01 102.63 103.66 103.98 105.82 105.89 106.30 112.02
DATA>  113.57 113.73 114.68 117.58 119.63 119.92 120.97 133.46
DATA> end
MTB > set c2
DATA>   81.53  91.60  95.55 100.34 102.89 103.39 104.81 105.00 106.02 106.43 106.51
DATA>  111.37 111.70 113.26 113.73 114.05 115.09 117.22 118.29 121.24 127.69 132.60
DATA>  137.79 137.97 143.20
DATA> end
MTB > Mann-Whitney C1 C2;
SUBC>   Alternative 0.
```

Output

```
Mann-Whitney Test: C1, C2 

     N  Median
C1  30  102.32
C2  25  111.70

Point estimate for η1 - η2 is -11.57
W = 683.5
Test of η1 = η2 vs η1 ≠ η2 is significant at 0.0084
The test is significant at 0.0084 (adjusted for ties)
```

Notice that the "W-statistics" differ, but the P-values are 0.0084
in both software packages. The observation `113.73` happens to occur
in both samples. This causes minor difficulties with the distribution
theory, handled slightly differently by the two programs.

Comment: Thanks Bruce!!!